# Expresión regular para nombres y puestos de trabajo

Tags: python, regex

Quisiera saber si hay una expresión regular para extraer todos los nombres y puestos de trabajo de un documento que esta de la siguiente forma:

`DIEGO SÁNCHEZ, GERENTE DE MARKETING: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...`

`FERNANDO VILA, GERENTE DE RECURSOS HUMANOS: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...`

`DIEGO SÁNCHEZ: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...`

`FERNANDO VILA: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..`

Después de haber aparecido por primera vez el nombre de una persona el puesto de trabajo ya no vuelve a aparecer.

He estado intentado por un tiempo crear una expresión pero no he tenido éxito :(

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] para enterarte de cómo funcionamos y luego consulta [ask]. Tu pregunta debe mostrar lo que has intentado y de ser posible incluir comentarios acerca de tus tropezones. La idea es que podamos ayudarte. No que lo hagamos por ti.

Answer (score 0):

No hay necesidad de usar expresiones regulares. Basta con separar el string por el primer ":". Con eso separamos nombre_cargo del Lorem ipsum,

A continuación sólo queda separar nombre de cargo en base a la ",", que puede venir o no. Si no viene, `split` levanta una excepción, que usamos para recuperar correctamente los valores.

```
[nombre_cargo, resto] = a.split(":", 1)
try:
    [nombre, puesto] = nombre_cargo.split(",", 1)
except ValueError:
    nombre = nombre_cargo
    puesto = None
    
print(nombre)
print(puesto)
```

Probamos con

```
a = "DIEGO SÁNCHEZ, GERENTE DE MARKETING: Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame"
```

produce

```
DIEGO SÁNCHEZ
 GERENTE DE MARKETING
```

y con

```
a = "DIEGO SÁNCHEZ: Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame"
```

produce

```
DIEGO SÁNCHEZ
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el formato de entrada siempre esté dado por esa manera que muestras, y en caso de que verdaderamente necesites una regex, puedes usar el módulo `re`, con su función `search`, junto con el siguiente patrón:

```
([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)(?:\, )?([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)?\:
```

**Explicación:**

- `([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)` Grupo que captura letras mayúsculas (incluyendo letras con acentos y espacios), destinado a capturar el nombre.
- `(?:\, )?` Grupo de no captura que establece como opcional la existencia de una coma seguida de un espacio.
- `([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)?` Grupo que captura letras mayúsculas (incluyendo letras con acentos y espacios), destinado a capturar el puesto de trabajo. Esto es opcional.
- `\:` El patrón culmina en dos puntos

**Integración con Python**

Como te mencioné, puedes usar este patrón con la función `re.search`. Si puedes agrupar todas las líneas en una lista, entonces puedes aplicar el siguiente código, el cual una una comprehensión de lista para generar el resultado que (creo) buscas:

```
import re


lines = ['DIEGO SÁNCHEZ, GERENTE DE MARKETING: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...',
         'FERNANDO VILA, GERENTE DE RECURSOS HUMANOS: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
         'DIEGO SÁNCHEZ: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
         'FERNANDO VILA: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..']

result = [re.search(r'([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)(?:\, )?([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ ]+)?\:', line).groups()
          for line in lines]
```

**Salida**

```
[('DIEGO SÁNCHEZ', 'GERENTE DE MARKETING'),
 ('FERNANDO VILA', 'GERENTE DE RECURSOS HUMANOS'),
 ('DIEGO SÁNCHEZ', None),
 ('FERNANDO VILA', None)]
```